# Abstracting away pyodbc connection in a function Python

Tags: python, pyodbc, abstraction

I'm running a lot of python scripts that need to access different servers of a SQL database.
I'm hoping to be ab le to abstract away some of the heavy lifting of connecting using pyodbc.
In a separate py file I'm defining the default driver and server (in the future I want to be able to add to this file so that different servers are easy to access)
And trying to write a function that returns a pandas dataframe as the result so that I'm not constantly connecting and disconnecting from our servers just to query some data.
Here is what I was thinking.

`

```
#imports
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 

default_driver = 'driverName'
default_server = 'serverName'

def sql_query(query, driver = default_driver, server = default_server):
    #accepts a T-SQL query, connects to the default server using the default driver 
    #returns a pandas datafram of the data 
    try:
        driver_server_string = 'DRIVER={' + str(driver) + '}; SERVER=' + str(server) +';TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(driver_server_string)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        result = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
        return result
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
        print('SQL Query returned an error')
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Right now Im running into two errors
And I'm also not sure if this is even the best way to accomplish my goal.
Importing this function with:

```
from environments import sql_query
```

returns
NameError: name 'sql_query' is not defined

And even in the same script I get a module not found
Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

Ideally I wanted to be able to have connection to a sql server as simple as
from pyFile import SomeClassOrFunction

data = sql_query('query',server = 'serverName')
and get a pandas df from the result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, I would say what you're doing is fine.

error 1: i don't think we have enough information to answer. an import error like this is likely the cause of something like how the file structure is set up that is making the other script not be able to see it.

error 2 (_multiarray_umath): specifically what line is giving that error?

FYI, Pandas has a function that you can just give a connection and a query to and it'll just return an data frame: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: I dont know why I didnt think to use the Pandas method. That is much easier thank you!